# Calling a function inside reduce / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reduce

My webpage isn't loading. However, if I moved the `$(".datacards").append(html)` into the `displayResults` function, everything loads fine. I just wanted to reduce all the calls into 1 string with reduce and then append it once, like in my code below. Except, it's not loading when I have it set up like this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    let streamers = [
  "joweed15",
  "overwatchleague",
  "blizzheroes",
  "freecodecamp",
  "nl_kripp",
  "drdisrespectlive",
  "ryuquezacotl",
  "queenmico",
  "timthetatman",
  "thijshs",
  "lilypichu",
  "arteezy"
];

function getStreamers() {
  // var html = "";
  var channelsAPI = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/";
  var streamsAPI = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/";
  var html = streamers.reduce(function(str, streamer) {
    $.getJSON(channelsAPI + streamer, function(data) {
      str += displayResults(
        data.display_name,
        data.name,
        data.logo,
        data.status
      );
    });
  }, "");
  $(".datacards").append(html)
}

function displayResults(display_name, name, logo, status) {
  return  `
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
        <p class="name">${display_name}</p>
        <div class="circle"><i class="fas fa-circle fa-1x"></i></div>
        <img src="${logo}" class="avatar">
        <p class="status text-center">${status}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON()` returns the XHR object, not the data you're requesting. It's also *asynchronous* which means the results will come later. That's why there's the callback function that handles the data. Thus `html` will contain an object and if you actually want the data that's returned from the API you'll handle it very differently. Just putting `reduce()` in front of any function call won't do what you want.

You have to do the calls and append data when new result is received. If you really want all data at once it's a bit trickier, but I don't think you need that. Just add the results from `displayResults` one by one.